# Replace object every 200 frames

Tags: c++

Beginner question so bear with me. How could I make this loop so every 200 frames the pine gets swapped with the tree?

```
int counter;

void swap(void) {
cout << counter++ << endl;
if (counter <= 200)
    drawPine(0, 0);
else
    drawTree(0, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
void swap() {
  static int counter = 0;
  if (counter % 400 < 200) {
    drawPine(0, 0);
  } else {
    drawTree(0, 0);
  }
  counter++;
}
```

Comment: And at `counter == INT_MAX`, we get overflow.

Comment: @Kaz For a 32 bit signed int being incremented 60 times per second, overflow happens after about 414 days.

Comment: If you make it `unsigned int`, the problem is that the range is not divisible by 400. A 32 bit `UINT_MAX` value modulo 400 is 96.

Comment: @Kaz ... which will happen in 2 years. It doesn't matter.  And that's assuming a 32-bit int which, these days, is the exception rather than the rule.

Comment: @3Dave The C compilers for most mainstream 64 bit environments have a 32 bit `int` type. (ISO C allows it to be as small as 16.)  Where did you read in the question that it's not a requirement to run correctly for two years or more? Also, where is the frame rate specified, and how do we even know that this is real-time rendering?

Answer (score 1):

```
int counter;

void swap(void) {
    cout << counter << endl;

    counter = (1 + counter) % 400;    
    if (counter < 200)
        drawPine(0, 0);
    else
        drawTree(0, 0);
}
```

Or, to avoid all the overflow silliness in the comments:

```
unsigned int counter;

void swap(void) {

    cout << counter++ << endl;

    if (counter % 512 < 256)
        drawPine(0, 0);
    else
        drawTree(0, 0);
}
```

Changing the flip interval to a power of 2 doesn't prevent the overflow that'll happen in 1.135... **years** when `counter` overflows int, but, since the new interval is a factor of `INT_MAX`, the system will continue to function correctly. Note that some embedded systems will trigger an interrupt when an overflow flag is set, and some of those will `jmp` to the reset vector. So, if you're running this on an HC11 in 1988, there might be a problem.

Comment: Another `int` overflow, with an off-by-one mistake. Modulo 400 values are from 0 to 399. The first 200 are 0 to 199, and the second 200 are from 200 to 399. So you need < 200 for an even split.

Comment: @Kaz fixed. Thanks. The overflow would cause a slight stutter after running for... INT_MAX frames. Changing `counter` to `unsigned int` and the interval to a power of 2 would eliminate that without the need for division. (Which is still, even in 2019, really slow.)

Comment: @Kaz Even for a 32-bit int, it would take 2.27 years to overflow. For 64-bit, it'd be about  9749040289.25... years. I'd call anything that has a frame stutter one every 2 years a win. This is at 60Hz, which will never happen with a `cout` in the loop.